# Google Drive API Quickstart.py Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I'm using the https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python to access the Google Drive Api but Google keeps throwing `redirect_uri_mismatch` errors.

I add the localhost:number from the error to the Authorised redirect URIs in the client ID for the Web Application, but whenever I run the `quickstart.py`, the local host number changes.

I see there are loads of questions regarding this matter on StackOverflow and I've already spent hours looking to fix mine but I haven't found an answer that seems to solve it for me.

Any ideas?

---

Tried answers from, amongst others,

- [Google Drive REST API DriveQuickstart Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282133/google-drive-rest-api-drivequickstart-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-java)
- [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)
- [Error: redirect_uri_mismatch pydrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585346/error-redirect-uri-mismatch-pydrive)

---

**Currently**

[image]

Comment: what is your redirect_uri?

Comment: I've removed all URIs I tried and kept only `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: By the way how you add code snippet in comment :p

Comment: See screenshot added of current setting. You add code in comment the same way as in the question: place the code between 2 `.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080` are different please make sure

Comment: You mean I should put 8000 in stead of 8080? I just added them to the URIs but issue persists.

Comment: No I'm saying please double check if you're using same redirect_uri on both side...because sometimes we use `http://localhost:8080/` and place redirect_uri `http://localhost:8080` both are different

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. Sadly it doesn't matter, issue still persists.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, if you are using [the script of Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python), please modify `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)` to `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)`, and test it again. When `port=0` is used, it seems that the random port is used.

Comment: Now I found your answer. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Also, now I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62982754/7108653). So this was the answer for your question. I apologize I couldn't find that before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google APIs OAuth 2.0 redirect\_uri\_mismatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62982754/google-apis-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-mismatch-error)

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)'s comment and answer here worked: [Google APIs OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62982754/google-apis-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-mismatch-error)

So in `quickstart.py`, make the following change,

```
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

to,

```
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
```

when `http://localhost:8080/` is on the URIs list.

Answer (score 0):

Like LucSpan mentioned in the comments of the answer. the redirect URI needs to be "http://localhost:8080/" and not "http://localhost:8080" the missing "/" at the end matters